# merge two list in R and preserve structure in the list

Tags: r, list, matrix, lapply

I have two list with multiple elements in `R`. Eaach element is in matrix format

list A has 10 rows 5 columns and list B has 5 rows and 5 columns, I would like to append each element in List B to list A. I would like to preserve the matrix structure in each element of the list. The newappended list would have 15 rows and 5 columns. Bascially I'm appending matrices from each list together.

As an example:

```
listA <- list(x=matrix(rnorm(50), nrow=10),
              y=matrix(rnorm(50), nrow=10))
listB <- list(x=matrix(rnorm(25), nrow=5),
              y=matrix(rnorm(25), nrow=5))
```

I tried few solutions in this site but both of them give vector and doe not preserve mXn structure.

```
k <- mapply(c,listA,listB,simplify=FALSE)

t <- apply(cbind(listA, listB),2,function(x) unname(unlist(x))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 listAB <- Map(`rbind`, listA, listB)
 sapply(listAB, dim)
 #     x  y
 #[1,] 15 15
 #[2,]  5  5
```